# delimiting by a char but not deleting it

Tags: matlab

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
(a (bee (cold down)))
```

if I load it using

```
c=textscan(fid,'%s');
```

I get this:

```
'(a'
'(bee'
'(cold'
'down)))'
```

What I would like to get is:

```
'('
'a'
'('
'bee'
'('
'cold'
'down'
')'     
')'
')'
```

I know I can delimit with '(' and ')' by specifying 'Delimiter' in textscan, but then I will loose this character, which I want to keep.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` specifier indicates that you want Strings, what you want is individual chars. Use  `%c` instead .

```
c=textscan(fid,'%c');
```

**Update** if you want too keep your words intact then you'll want to load your text using the `%s` specifier.  After the text is loaded you can either solve this problem with Regular Expressions (not my forte)  or write your own parser then parses each word individually and saves the paranthesis and words to a new cell array.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify some of the letters might be words. Please see edit.

Comment: I think you'd have to take what you have and use regexp or something like that to split your string down even more.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no canned routine capable of preserving arbitrary delimiters. 
You'd have to do it yourself:

```
string = '(a (bee (cold down)))';

bo = string == '(';
bc = string == ')';
sp = string == ' ';

output = cell(nnz(bo|bc|sp)+1,1);
j = 1;

for ii = 1:numel(string)
    if bo(ii) 
        output{j} = '(';
        j = j + 1;

    elseif bc(ii) 
        output{j} = ')';
        j = j + 1;

    elseif sp(ii) 
        j = j + 1;

    else
        output{j} = [output{j} string(ii)];

    end
end
```

Which can probably be improved -- the growing character array will prevent the loop from being JIT'ed. The array `bc | bo | sp` holds all the information to vectorize this thing, I just don't see how at this hour...

Nevertheless, it should give you a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has a `strtok` function similar to C. Its format is:

```
token = strtok(str)
token = strtok(str, delimiter)
[token, remain] = strtok('str', ...)
```

there is also a string replace function `strrep`:

```
modifiedStr = strrep(origStr, oldSubstr, newSubstr)
```

What I would do is modify the original string with `strrep` to add in delimiters, then use `strtok`.  Since you already scanned the string into `c`:

```
c = (c,'(','( '); %Add a space after each open paren
c = (c,')',' ) '); % Add a space before and after each close paren
token = zeros(10); preallocate for speed
i = 2;
[token(1), remain] = strtok(c, ' ');
while(remain)
    [token(i), remain] = strtok(c, ' ');
    i =i + 1;
end
```

gives you the linear token array of each of the string you requested.

`strtok` reference: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strtok.html

`strrep` reference: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strrep.html

Comment: Strtok is available in newer versions of matlab, I'm not sure which

Comment: -1: there's several issues with this...first, replacing every occurence of `'('` with `'( '` (same for `')'`) has performance issues. Second, your code doesn't handle the replacing at all -- it's just pseudo code. And not just that, it is *buggy* pseudo code.

Comment: Did you read the mathworks reference on "strrep?"  That is the format and that will add the white space I want.  Which will be fine when strtok removes it two lines later.   Is "strrep" slow, what performance issues are you talking about precisely?

Comment: Imagine `c` is not the simple string you see, but a monstrous multi-million character string. Replacing all occurrences of `'('` with `'( '`, and `')'` with `') '` then already requires two reads of the full array, and two complete re-writes (of a *grown* array mind you). And then you haven't even started splitting it up yet! It's simply not efficient.